# How to prevent a key-binding from registering as an evil-mode operator?

Tags: evil

When wrapping save in a function so it always writes, *(used so I can trigger compilation which I have set to watch my files).*

```
(defun save-buffer-always ()
  "Save the buffer even if it is not modified."
  (interactive)
  (set-buffer-modified-p t)
  (save-buffer))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-s") 'save-buffer-always)
```

While this works, evil mode 'dot' operator now registers saving as an operation, so repeat-last (dot operator) doesn't repeat my last edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evil stores and retrieves repeat information for commands to track whether and how they shall be repeated or whether they shouldn't.  `evil-declare-abort-repeat` is the one used for `save-buffer` as seen in `evil-integration.el`:

```
(mapc #'evil-declare-abort-repeat
      '(balance-windows
        eval-expression
        execute-extended-command
        exit-minibuffer
        compile
        delete-window
        delete-other-windows
        find-file-at-point
        ffap-other-window
        recompile
        redo
        save-buffer
        split-window
        split-window-horizontally
        split-window-vertically
        undo
        undo-tree-redo
        undo-tree-undo))
```

You can therefore achieve the same effect for your own command with `(evil-declare-abort-repeat 'save-buffer-always)`.  Details on what the other repeat properties do can be found in `evil-repeat.el`.